# Changing CKEditor configuration language on button click dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ckeditor

I need to change the content and UI language of the CKEditor5 when I click a button. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hymn.png) of the app. On each button click, the `config` is updated with the new language selected. But the CKEditor remains with the same configuration when it has been initialized. How can we modify the content and UI of the editor dynamically using Angular or TypeScript?
**Note: I'm using Angular 5, Angular CLI 1.7.4. And also I'm using CKEditor5 version 1.2.3**

Here's the .ts component code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { ChangeEvent } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular'
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'

@Component({
  selector: 'another-text-editor',
  templateUrl: './another-text-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./another-text-editor.component.css']
})
export class TextEditorComponent implements OnInit{

  languages = [
    { id: 'fr', label: 'French' },
    { id: 'de', label: 'German' },
    { id: 'ar', label: 'Arabic' }
  ]

  public Editor = ClassicEditor

  config = {
    toolbar: ['bold', 'italic'],
    language: { ui: 'fr', content: 'fr' }
  }

  constructor () {}

  ngOnInit () {}

  changeConfig (lang) {
    this.config = {
      ...this.config,
      language: {
        ui: lang,
        content: lang
      }
    }
  }

  public onChange ({editor}: ChangeEvent) {
     console.log(editor.getData())
  }
}
```

And here's the HTML code for the component:

```html
<div class="container pt-4">
  <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" id="editor" tagName="textarea" [config]="config" [(ngModel)]="text" (change)="onChange($event)"></ckeditor>
  <div class="row justify-content-start align-items-center mt-4">
    <div class="col-auto" *ngFor="let lang of languages">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="changeConfig(lang)">
        Click for {{lang.label}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added the translation files in `.angular-cli.json`:

```json
"scripts": [ 
        "../node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/translations/de.js",
        "../node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/translations/fr.js",
        "../node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/translations/ar.js"
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not possible yet to change the UI dinamically when the language changes. There is a github issue opened in the library's repo, a [feature request for that](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/9498). You could try triggering a manual re-render.

I let some guidance for how to do a hack for this in React.js here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/9498#issuecomment-1569452422 in case someone is coming here looking for this answer in such framework. I tested that and it worked.

In Angular, a solution could be:

1 - Update the `Editor` object based on the selected language: Instead of assigning the `ClassicEditor` directly to `Editor`, you'll assign the corresponding language build based on the selected language:

```
public Editor: any;

changeConfig(lang: string) {
  switch (lang) {
    case 'de':
      this.Editor = ClassicEditorDE;
      break;
    case 'ar':
      this.Editor = ClassicEditorAR;
      break;
    default:
      this.Editor = ClassicEditor;
      break;
  }

  this.config = {
    ...this.config,
    language: {
      ui: lang,
      content: lang
    }
  };
}
```

2 - Update the HTML template: Update the `<ckeditor>` element in your HTML template to use the dynamic `Editor` and `config` properties:

```
<div class="container pt-4">
  <ckeditor
    [editor]="Editor"
    id="editor"
    tagName="textarea"
    [config]="config"
    [(ngModel)]="text"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
  ></ckeditor>
  <div class="row justify-content-start align-items-center mt-4">
    <div class="col-auto" *ngFor="let lang of languages">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="changeConfig(lang.id)">
        Click for {{ lang.label }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With these changes, when you click a language button, the `changeConfig()` method will update the `Editor` object based on the selected language. The corresponding language build will be loaded, and the CKEditor5 instance will be recreated with the new configuration, including the updated language.

Answer (score 0):

First Destroy the current editor instance using the:

```
document.querySelector('.ck-editor__editable').ckeditorInstance.destroy();
```

Then recreate the instance on the selected ID:

```
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#content' ), { options }
```